# Estimate of the length of a curve via average number of intersection with spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, integral-geometry

This is a problem in integral geometry. I can't prove or find a proof of the following inequality :

Let $\beta$ be a simple closed curve and $Box(r)=\{|x|< r, |y|< 2^{1/3}r, |z|< 2^{2/3}r\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}³$ and $\epsilon>0$ be fixed. Then
$$ \int_1^{1+\epsilon} \#(\beta \cap \partial Box(r))dr \leq Length(\beta \cap Box(1+\epsilon)) $$

It sounds like Crofton's formula and isn't hard to believe in $\mathbb{R}²$ with circles instead of boxes. 
Does anyone have a reference or a proof?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is a reference containing this problem ?

Comment: It comes from the paper of John Pardon, On the distortion of knots on embedded surfaces, the arXiv reference is : [arXiv:1010.1972](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.1972)

Comment: If we approximate $\beta\cap Box(1+\epsilon)$ with a polyline, the claim should be clear.  If the number of intersection points with the original $\beta$ is larger than with the polyline approximation on a set of positive measure, the approximation simply wasn't good enough ...

Comment: I agree with @HagenvonEitzen . My only problem is how to write explicitely  the left hand side (the integral)... Thank's